# Is CryptoNight the hash function which plays the role of the "random oracle"?

Tags: security, cryptography, cryptonote, cryptonight, algorithm

Is CryptoNight the hash function which plays the role of the "random oracle" in the random oracle model under which certain properties of CryptoNote are mathematically proven in the original paper? Or am I confusing concepts?

If I'm confusing concepts, what is the "random oracle" hash function in CryptoNote?

And how much do we know about the likelihood that the algorithm is good enough to reasonably approximate the behavior of a random oracle and how does that impact the validity of the proofs in the paper, do we have reasons to worry that it might have some bad behavior which would invalidate the Linkability/Exculpability/Unforgeability/Anonimity properties?

Answer (score 3):

The *Hp* and *Hs* hash functions of the Cryptonote paper are called `hash_to_ec` and `hash_to_scalar` in the Monero code base, and they are based on the Keccak1600 hash function (called `fast_hash` in the code), not Cryptonight (called `slow-hash` in the code).